# textTabs ordering in consistent in returned array

Tags: docusignapi

Can I expect textTabs contains to be returned in the same order since or do I need to access them via the tabLabel? The data structure is an array each time, so I was hoping use that ordering. At the moment the same document has these fields in different orders "some" of the time. Mostly so, even though it's the same document. Very strange.

Thanks,
Gavin.

Comment: Can you please share what are you trying to achieve, what you have tried and what are you seeing vs whats expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation for all object types (documents, tabs, recipients, templates applied, etc) is that you rely on an explicit, unique identifier instead of the order of appearance.